# It's in + address

Tags: prepositions

Is the right preposition to use **in** in this kind of sentence?

It's (the restaurant) in 54 London Street, Rome

Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score -1):

I would say "at". Like "I live at 2328 Macomb Street", or "He lives at the corner of Connecticut Avenue and 41st." "The restaurant's at 54 London Street" or you could less specifically say "The restaurant's on London Street". Or just "the address is... ". But I would not say 'in' here.

Using "in" here would imply to me that the restaurant, or house, or whichever, was inside of some larger place -- "in" might be okay if it wasn't an address with just the restaurant at it but many stores. Even if this were true, I would probably specify that, like "It's in the mall at 1500 Wisconsin Avenue". An address isn't a thing that it feels natural for something to be "inside". You're in a country, and you're in a city, but, in the same sense that you're at work, at school, or at the park, you're at a specific street address.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you would not use "in"?

Comment: Using "in" here would imply to me that the restaurant, or house, or whichever, was inside of some larger place -- "in" might be okay if it wasn't an address with just the restaurant at it but many stores. Even if this were true, I would probably specify that, like "It's in the mall at 1500 Wisconsin Avenue". An address isn't a thing that it feels natural for something to be "inside". You're in a country, and you're in a city, but, in the same sense that you're at work, at school, or at the park, you're at a specific street address. Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes thanks, you can include your comment explanation inside your answer to make it more complete. comments can be deleted so its better to put it inside the answer :-)